# java jni self wake up on usb

Tags: usb, java-native-interface, driver, device

I have an existing java and JNI based application which reads successfully from a usb device. I need to add a feature that when the device is plugged in, my application should wake up. Can anybody please point to similar solutions with examples and docs ? i need to do this in mac only.

Comment: Can you give more information on the "JNI based application..."

Comment: the jni[java native interface in  c++] component reads data from usb and passes it over to swing based java program.